# MVC ddl value after postback

Tags: model-view-controller, ddl

I have a ddl which is populated with hours of day 01-23. This is on a form which is used to book an item of equipment. The hour is populated to a db field. The issue is this, when the booking form is opened to alter the time the ddl shows the hour that was booked, when changed though and the form is submitted the value passed on post is the initial value from db not the new selected hour.

this is the basic pieces of code. any idea why the newly selected ddl value is not passed to the model??

View

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("ddl_Hour", Model.ddlHour,
 new { @class = "DropDown", style = "width: 40px” })%>
```

Model

```
private string _ddlHourSelectedValue = "0";
public SelectList ddlHour
        {
            get
            {
                return (new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(_ddlHour, "intValue", "Text", Convert.ToInt32(_ddlHourSelectedValue)));
            }
        }
public string ddlHourSelectedValue
        {
            get
            {
                return _ddlHourSelectedValue;
            }
            set
            {
                _ddlHourSelectedValue = value;
            }
        }



param[6] = new SqlParameter("@Timeslot", ddlHourSelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field in your view is called "ddl_Hour" However is there a variable in your Model with the same name? Otherwise the MVC framework will not automatically populate the value in the model.

Two ways you could go about this.

**1**

In your controller methods that accepts a post, you can add the parameter:

```
FormCollection fc
```

to the method. This key value pair collection will allow you to fetch results from fields in the post data like so:

```
string selectedValue = fc["ddl_Hour"];
```

**2**

Or you can modify your model to include a variable with the same name as the drop down list so that it is automatically populated for you.

```
public string ddl_Hour { get; set; }
```

You should then be able to access the result of the drop down list selection on post from that variable.

Comment: Apologies, my copy paste was incorrect I have amended it. The model does have the variable

      public SelectList ddlHour

Comment: The problem is this: 
`<%= Html.DropDownList("ddl_Hour", Model.ddlHour,
 new { @class = "DropDown", style = "width: 40px” })%>`

This posts the selected value of the drop down to your application with an id of "ddl_Hour". As there is no string variable in your model with the same name it will not be automatically available to you. If you rename your variable `public string ddlHourSelectedValue` to `ddl_Hour` you should find the value you select and post will be populated in your model.